# Variable number of for loops in R

Tags: r

I'm working in R and would like to pass a vector to a function.  The vector gives the maximum values for a series of for loops.  If the vector is (3,4,6,5), then the following code should be run.  So the number of for loops depends on the length of the vector that is passed to the function.  Then for each possibility, the counters are input into another function fn.  Provided an example for a possible fn below.

```
S=0
fn = function(x){sum(x^2)}

for (i in 0:3){
   for (j in 0:4){
      for (k in 0:6){
         for (l in 0:5){
            S=S+fn(c(i,j,k,l))
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

I believe recursion is the way to go here, but I haven't had any luck figuring it out, and most of the recursion examples I've seen seem to be at a very high or very low level.

Any idea what the best way to approach this problem is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to use loops

```
f <- function(vec, fn){
  vecs <- mapply(seq, 0, vec)
  tmp <- do.call(expand.grid, vecs)
  tmp <- apply(tmp, 1, fn)
  sum(tmp)
}

fn = function(x){sum(x^2)}
f(c(3, 4, 6, 5), fn = fn)
```

Comment: @user20650 If you want you can do that.  It doesn't meet the OP's specification and requires more work though.  It also just applies the function to the entire expanded grid instead of row-wise.  It gives the same answer in this case but if you were to treat the columns differently it might not work out.

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful.  I should mention - the vectors can be quite long and the values in the vector can be quite large.  Is this a relatively quick solution or could it be improved somehow?

Comment: @user3666707 There is probably room for improvement.  The object created by expand.grid will be quite large if there are a lot of big numbers in your vector.

Answer (score 1):

I like @Dason's version using `expand.grid`, but here is a recursive version for cases when that approach may not work, or for general enlightenment:

```
recfun <- function(a,b) {
    S <- 0
    if(length(b)) {
        for( i in seq(0,b[1]) ) {
            S <- S + Recall( c(a,i), b[-1] )
        }
    } else {
        return(fn(a))
    }
    S
}

recfun( numeric(0), c(3,4,6,5) )
```

For practical use you may want to wrap this in another function that that takes the vector of interest and passes it to the function as `b` with the empty vector as `a`.

Answer (score 0):

@Dason's answer is very nice but fails when all elements of `vec` are equal (because `mapply` then converts the result from a list to a matrix, whereas `do.call` requires a list). This can be rectified by adding `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`:

```
class(mapply(seq, 0, c(2, 2)))
[1] "matrix"
class(mapply(seq, 0, c(2, 2), SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
[1] "list"
```

The amended solution is then

```
f <- function(vec, fn){
  vecs <- mapply(seq, 0, vec, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
  tmp <- do.call(expand.grid, vecs)
  tmp <- apply(tmp, 1, fn)
  sum(tmp)
}

fn = function(x){sum(x^2)}
f(c(3, 4, 6, 5), fn = fn)
```